# constexpr constructor cannot be used in constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, unique-ptr, constexpr

I want to redefine `unique_ptr` with a special destructor.  Therefore I use the following code where I try to mimic some constructors of `unique_ptr`.  Unfortunately `constexpr` constructors refuse to build and I have no idea why.

```
class job_ptr : public unique_ptr<Job>
{
public:
    constexpr job_ptr()
        : unique_ptr<Job>(), sequencer( nullptr ) {}
    constexpr job_ptr( nullptr_t )
        : unique_ptr<Job>( nullptr ), sequencer( nullptr ) {}
private:
    FIFOSequencer* sequencer;
};
```

Both constructors in the initialisation list are declared `constexpr`, however `clang++` considers that `constexpr constructor never produces a constant expression` because `non-literal type 'unique_ptr<Job>' cannot be used in a constant expression`.  What does it try to mean ?  `constexpr` constructors cannot be used within `constexpr` constructors ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need a literal type. You don't have one. And `std::unique_ptr` lets you provide a custom deleter. Inheriting from it (especially publicly and for that purpose) is a terrible idea.

Comment: I totally agree with @chris inheriting from STL is encouraged in certain circumstances and `unique_ptr` is not the one IMHO.

Comment: A literal type needs a trivial destructor. In general, `unique_ptr` therefore cannot be a literal type.

Comment: A non-literal type can have a `constexpr` constructor as well. Its use is however quite limited AFAIK; you cannot use (create etc.) an object of non-literal type as a(n evaluated) part of a constant-expression. The constexpr ctor allows however to initialize an object of non-literal type during *constant initialization*.

Comment: So from what you all say, I'm required not to use inheritance but to copy-paste every single method signature of unique_ptr and forward the call ?  That's pretty cumbersome.  Thank you anyway.  Or maybe there is some smart way to use the `deleter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constexpr constructors are possibles, but [the requirement are quite strict](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). The main problem for you is, as @dyp said, that `std::unique_ptr` as no trivial destructor and thus is not a  [`LiteralType`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType).

If you try with an `int` under g++:

```
class int_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<int>
{
public:
    constexpr int_ptr()
        : std::unique_ptr<int>(), sequencer( nullptr ) {}
    constexpr int_ptr( nullptr_t )
        : std::unique_ptr<int>( nullptr ), sequencer( nullptr ) {}
private:
    int* sequencer;
};

constexpr int_ptr ptr;
```

You have a very explicit error message :

```
unique_ptr.cpp:40:20: error: the type ‘const int_ptr’ of constexpr variable ‘ptr’ is not literal
  constexpr int_ptr ptr;
                    ^
unique_ptr.cpp:27:7: note: ‘int_ptr’ is not literal because:
 class int_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<int>
       ^
unique_ptr.cpp:27:7: note:   ‘int_ptr’ has a non-trivial destructor
```

In your case, as suggested in the comment, use a custom deleter. STL container are not really well suited for inheritance.

Here an example of a custom deleter:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Deleter
{
    void operator()(T* t)
    {
        std::cout << "Deleter::oerator(): " << t << std::endl;
        delete t;
    }
};

struct A 
{
    A() 
    {
        std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A() 
    {
        std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<A, Deleter<A>> ptr(new A);


    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
A::A()
Deleter::oerator(): 0x600010480
A::~A()
```

([live run](http://ideone.com/ohWuTC)

Comment: @dyp Badly worded, i should have said `LiteralType`.

Comment: @dyp you're right, my check was badly done. Editing.

Comment: Thank you, however I need to use a deleter that holds my `FIFOSequencer* sequencer` but there seems to be constructors that accepts an already-build deleter.  I checked the gcc source code for unique_ptr, I didn't know there was actually an instance of deleter contained in the uniq_ptr.